# How to pass TextEditingController to add into list

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, arguments

I'm learning flutter and have a floating action button which opens a bottom sheet with some field inputs and date input to create an expense item.

I want to add the inputs to a dummy list of expenses I've already hardcoded. I believe I do this with a function and call `setState((){variable.add(argument);});`

The thing I really struggle with in Flutter is passing data between widgets, using arguments and constructors etc. Sorry for the dump of code - unsure how to share.

[image]
[image]

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'screens/home.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: const HomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

home.dart

```
import 'package:expenses_v2/widgets/expenses_summary.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../widgets/floating_action_button.dart';
import '../widgets/transactions_list.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 27, 27, 38),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            children: const [
              ExpensesSummary(),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              TransactionList(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: const CustomFloatingActionButton(),
    );
  }
}
```

transactions_list.dart

```
import 'package:expenses_v2/k_constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

import '../models/transactions.dart';

final List<Transaction> transactions = [
  Transaction(
    id: '1',
    title: 'New shoes',
    amount: 69.99,
    date: DateTime.now(),
  ),
  Transaction(
    id: '2',
    title: 'Weekly groceries',
    amount: 42.99,
    date: DateTime.now(),
  ),
];

class TransactionList extends StatelessWidget {
  const TransactionList({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  void addTransaction(String item, double cost) {}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: transactions.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                ListTile(
                  tileColor: kprimaryColour,
                  title: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text(transactions[index].title),
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          Text('£${transactions[index].amount}'),
                          Text(
                            DateFormat('d-mm-yy')
                                .format(transactions[index].date),
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: ksecondaryColour,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 2)
              ],
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

floatingactionbutton.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:expenses_v2/k_constants.dart';

class CustomFloatingActionButton extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomFloatingActionButton({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CustomFloatingActionButton> createState() =>
      _CustomFloatingActionButtonState();
}

class _CustomFloatingActionButtonState
    extends State<CustomFloatingActionButton> {
  //
  final itemInput = TextEditingController();
  final costInput = TextEditingController();
  DateTime? dateInput;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: kaccentColour,
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          showModalBottomSheet(
              constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 600),
              isScrollControlled: true,
              backgroundColor: ksecondaryColour,
              context: context,
              builder: (context) {
                return SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        const Text('Add an expense item'),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        TextField(
                          controller: itemInput,
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            hintText: 'Item',
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        TextField(
                          controller: costInput,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            hintText: 'Cost',
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        // TextField(
                        //   onChanged: (value) => dateInput = value,
                        //   keyboardType: TextInputType.datetime,
                        //   decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        //     border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        //     hintText: 'Date',
                        //   ),
                        // ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 200,
                          // Quick means to get a date picker in
                          child: CupertinoDatePicker(
                              onDateTimeChanged: (newDate) =>
                                  dateInput = newDate),
                        ),
                        ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.pop(context);
                              debugPrint(itemInput.text);
                              debugPrint(costInput.text);
                              debugPrint(dateInput.toString());
                              //TODO: Not sure if I need to clear the variables after submiting - unsure of best practice
                              // itemInput.text = '';
                              // costInput.text = '';
                              // dateInput = '';
                            },
                            child: const Text('Submit'))
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              });
        });
  }
}
```

transactions.dart

```
class Transaction {
  Transaction({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.amount,
    required this.date,
  });
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final double amount;
  final DateTime date;
}
```

k_constants.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Color kprimaryColour = const Color.fromARGB(255, 23, 37, 54);
Color ksecondaryColour = const Color.fromARGB(255, 73, 99, 130);
Color kaccentColour = const Color.fromARGB(255, 29, 209, 209);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a callback method to return data from  `CustomFloatingActionButton` widget. and pass `transactions` to the `TransactionList` instead of creating global variable. Also the  `HomePage` needed to be statefulWiget to update the UI.

```dart
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final List<Transaction> transactions = [
    Transaction(
      id: '1',
      title: 'New shoes',
      amount: 69.99,
      date: DateTime.now(),
    ),
    Transaction(
      id: '2',
      title: 'Weekly groceries',
      amount: 42.99,
      date: DateTime.now(),
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 27, 27, 38),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              // ExpensesSummary(),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              TransactionList(transactions: transactions),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: CustomFloatingActionButton(
        callback: (transaction) {
          if (transaction != null) {
            transactions.add(transaction);

            print(transaction);
            setState(() {});
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TransactionList extends StatelessWidget {
  final transactions;
  const TransactionList({
    Key? key,
    required this.transactions,
  }) : super(key: key);

  void addTransaction(String item, double cost) {}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: transactions.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                ListTile(
                  tileColor: kprimaryColour,
                  title: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text(transactions[index].title),
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          Text('£${transactions[index].amount}'),
                          Text(
                            DateFormat('d-mm-yy')
                                .format(transactions[index].date),
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: ksecondaryColour,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 2)
              ],
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}

class CustomFloatingActionButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(Transaction? transaction) callback;

  const CustomFloatingActionButton({
    Key? key,
    required this.callback,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CustomFloatingActionButton> createState() =>
      _CustomFloatingActionButtonState();
}

class _CustomFloatingActionButtonState
    extends State<CustomFloatingActionButton> {
  //
  final itemInput = TextEditingController();
  final costInput = TextEditingController();
  DateTime? dateInput;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: kaccentColour,
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () async {
          showModalBottomSheet(
              constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 600),
              isScrollControlled: true,
              backgroundColor: ksecondaryColour,
              context: context,
              builder: (context) {
                return SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        const Text('Add an expense item'),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        TextField(
                          controller: itemInput,
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            hintText: 'Item',
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        TextField(
                          controller: costInput,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            hintText: 'Cost',
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        // TextField(
                        //   onChanged: (value) => dateInput = value,
                        //   keyboardType: TextInputType.datetime,
                        //   decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        //     border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        //     hintText: 'Date',
                        //   ),
                        // ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 200,
                          // Quick means to get a date picker in
                          child: CupertinoDatePicker(
                              onDateTimeChanged: (newDate) =>
                                  dateInput = newDate),
                        ),
                        ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.pop(context);
                              debugPrint(itemInput.text);
                              debugPrint(costInput.text);
                              debugPrint(dateInput.toString());

                              final result = Transaction(
                                  amount: double.tryParse(costInput.text) ?? 0,
                                  date: dateInput ?? DateTime.now(),
                                  id: "your Id",
                                  title: itemInput.text);

                              widget.callback(result);
                            },
                            child: const Text('Submit'))
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              });
        });
  }
}
```